# Rails 5 compiled js code does not work on production only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, production, turbolinks

I have a js code which should add a class to all images within an element with a class:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.blog-article img').addClass('img-fluid');
});
```

View where it should work looks like:

```
<div class="blog-article">
  <p><img src="http://image_address..." alt=""></p>
</div>
```

in development environment it works perfect. *But in production environment this code does not work* although I can see it in assets using browser console:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load",function(){$(".blog-article img").addClass("img-fluid")});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

PS. application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('.blog-article img').addClass('img-fluid');
});
```

PPS. And interesting moment - when I see in console in production, js code looks like this:

[image]

and it has extra spaces, so it might be the causing reason. But when I rename slass replacing - with _ or removing it or leaving just .article, it still has extra spaces in production:

```
.blog-      article
.blog_      article
.blog       article
.      article
```

And I have everything correct in development (as described above).

And the interesting point - if I copy the code from console, these "extra spaces" disappear.

Comment: Can you paste your application.js please? I had a similar issue which had to do with load order.

Comment: @rorykoehler added in the description. thank you!

Comment: and why do you write the custom js on application.js? which is not a good practise at all

Comment: just to show you. it does not depend on where I put the code, finally it does not work in production...

Comment: can you paste the console error message, the screenshot is not helpful.

Comment: there is a strange error message "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether". But I do not think is about my problem.

Comment: I just fixed the "tether" problem, and everything is correct with js now... issue is solved...

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using bootstrap. Bootstrap 4 requires 'tether' to work without generating errors. And because compiled javascript is compressed to only one row, all javascript stops working if you get errors :)

Does it work better if you install Tether?

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/README.md#installation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you initiating the .js.coffee as following

```
jQuery ($) ->
   $(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
```

Comment: I tried to put it in a separate coffee file, but the result is the same - in development it works, in production - not, although the code is compiled and exists in production (I can see it in browser console)

Comment: Try the rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: the thing is that assets are precompiled by Capistrano. After I moved my code in a separate coffee file, it looks in production like this: jQuery(function(t){return t(document).on("turbolinks:load",function(){return t(".blog-article img").addClass("img-fluid")} So I suppose it should work...

Comment: Hope my comment helped you "Moving the js to separate file"

Comment: I added a screenshot from a console in the issue description - please could you take a look? The problem still persists